# Uniform stochastic process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Is it possible to construct a stochastic process $X_t$, $t \in [0, +\infty)$ such that for each $t$, 
$X_t$ be uniform on, say, $[0,1]$ by using Kolmogorov's compatibility theorem ?

Comment: Well, there's the trivial one where $U$ is a $U(0,1)$ r.v. and $X_t=U$ for all $t$. The more interesting question is what happens if you postulate some kind of covariance property, such as loss of correlation over time.

Comment: Ok. But writing $X(t,\omega)$ do you mean $ X(t,\omega)=U(\omega)$ in which case the paths are constant w.r. to t. What if I want a new random number every t ?

Comment: If you require that  $\text{cov}(U_t,U_s)=\delta_{t,s}$ then answer is NO, such random process does not exist in classical sense (measurable random variable), only as a week random variable (same situation as with white noise).

Comment: Ok, thanks iiivooo. Is the non-existence proof difficult ? And then what comes closest to independence at different times ? How would then one simulate such a process ?

Comment: @GeorgK So the proof I know is based on extending cylindrical measures to $\sigma$ algebra, see chapter 6 of [this book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781461258674) if you are interested. In practise you can always simulate only finitely many samples, so you work only with discrete process, so you do not need to worry about existence.

Comment: Thanks again iiivooo. I took a look at the book and the proof. What about having a covariance close to a Dirac ?